# Connect() Returns 0 Linux Socket programming (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

So I am trying to write a simple c++ socket program (Ubuntu) where all it does is connect to google and tells me it did so (Through port 80). I decide to print out the results of the `connect()` and `socket` commands. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<iostream> 
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    std::cout << socket_desc;
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.217.12.46");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    std::cout << (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)));
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)    
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of code:

```
30connect error
```

(It was late at night and I was too lazy to do line breaks)

So my question is: Does 0 mean no data was sent or the connection was not established? Why does it execute the connect error line of code even though 0 = 0 not less than 0?

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: "Does 0 mean no data was sent or the connection was not established?" http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html "Why does it execute the connect error line of code even though 0 = 0 not less than 0?" Only because your first connect returns 0 doesn't mean your second connect returns 0 aswell

Comment: When you get an error from a system call, `puts()` of your own message is not sufficient. You must show the actual error, via `errno` or `strerror()` or `perror()`. If you had done that, you would have seen immediately that the socket was already connected.

Comment: Also you are leaking sockets if the connect fails.

Answer (score 8):

The return value of 0 from `connect()` means that the connection succeeded.

But immediately after you print the return value from `connect()` -- directly into `std::cout` using the `<<` operator -- the shown code calls `connect()` a second time with the same socket.

That is an error, because the socket is already connected, and that's why your `if()` statement reports an error. You called `connect()` twice. That's your bug.

Answer (score 1):

this :

```
 //Connect to remote server
std::cout << (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)));
if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)    
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}
```

to :

```
//Connect to remote server
result = connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
std::cout << "connect result : " << result << std::endl;
if (result < 0)    
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}
```